# AppCompatActivity not implementing LifecycleOwner

Tags: java, android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-lifecycle

I am using Android Support Library `26.1.0`. These are the dependencies in the app module:

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-beta1"
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.0.0-beta1"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:1.0.0-beta1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0-beta1"
```

But when I am trying to use ViewModel like the below:

```
mUserViewModel.getUsers().observe(this,
            (Observer<Resource<List<UserView>>>) listResource -> {
                if(listResource != null){
                    this.handleDataState(listResource.status, listResource.data, listResource.message);
                }
            });
```

It is showing error at `this` and the error message is `Wrong first argument type Found: packagename.BrowseActivity, required: android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner`. (Although support library version is 26.1+ which already implements LifecycleOwner)

I have also tried to implement `LifecycleRegistryOwner` which I found in this [sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/MainActivity.java) and this is also not working. Kindly suggest a solution and let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

**Edit 1** -
This is an Activity class:

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.Observer;
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.github.amitkma.boilerplate.app.R;
import com.github.amitkma.boilerplate.app.mapper.UserMapper;
import com.github.amitkma.boilerplate.app.model.UserModel;
import com.github.amitkma.boilerplate.app.ui.widget.EmptyView;
import com.github.amitkma.boilerplate.app.ui.widget.ErrorView;
import com.github.amitkma.boilerplate.presentation.data.Resource;
import com.github.amitkma.boilerplate.presentation.data.ResourceState;
import com.github.amitkma.boilerplate.presentation.factory.ViewModelFactory;
import com.github.amitkma.boilerplate.presentation.viewmodel.UserViewModel;
import com.github.amitkma.boilerplate.presentation.vo.UserView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import dagger.android.AndroidInjection;

public class BrowseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject
    UserAdapter mUserAdapter;
    @Inject
    UserMapper mUserMapper;
    @Inject
    ViewModelFactory mViewModelFactory;
    private UserViewModel mUserViewModel;

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private ErrorView mErrorView;
    private EmptyView mEmptyView;


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       AndroidInjection.inject(this);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_browse);
       mUserViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, mViewModelFactory)
            .get(UserViewModel.class);

       mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_browse);
       mProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress);
       mEmptyView = findViewById(R.id.view_empty);
       mErrorView = findViewById(R.id.view_error);

       setupBrowseRecycler();
       setupViewListeners();
   }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mUserViewModel.getUsers().observe(this,
            (Observer<Resource<List<UserView>>>) listResource -> {
                if(listResource != null){
                    this.handleDataState(listResource.status, listResource.data, listResource.message);
                }
            });
    }
    ....
}
```

This is ViewModel Class:

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData;
import android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel;

import com.github.amitkma.boilerplate.domain.interactor.GetUserList;
import com.github.amitkma.boilerplate.domain.model.User;
import com.github.amitkma.boilerplate.presentation.data.Resource;
import com.github.amitkma.boilerplate.presentation.data.ResourceState;
import com.github.amitkma.boilerplate.presentation.mapper.UserMapper;
import com.github.amitkma.boilerplate.presentation.vo.UserView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import io.reactivex.subscribers.DisposableSubscriber;

public class UserViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private final GetUserList mGetUserList;
    private final UserMapper mUserMapper;

    @Inject
    public UserViewModel(GetUserList getUserList,
            UserMapper userMapper) {
        mGetUserList = getUserList;
        mUserMapper = userMapper;
        fetchUsers();
    }

    public void fetchUsers(){
        mUserMutableLiveData.postValue(new Resource(ResourceState.LOADING, null, null));
        mGetUserList.execute(new UserSubscriber(), null);
    }

    public LiveData<Resource<List<UserView>>> getUsers(){
        return mUserMutableLiveData;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCleared() {
        mGetUserList.dispose();
        super.onCleared();
    }

    private final MutableLiveData<Resource<List<UserView>>> mUserMutableLiveData =
        new MutableLiveData<>();
}
```

Comment: You need to post more code. Show the Activity's `import`s and class definition.

Comment: I have added the code. Please have a look.

Comment: I dont see any problem except that you import DisposableSubscriber in your ViewModel which is not needed.

Comment: I have not pasted the inner Subscriber class just because it is not related to this issue anyhow.

Comment: Please try to set the arch version to 1.0.0-alpha9-1.

Comment: I have set the version to 1.0.0-alpha9-1 and it worked and then again I replaced it with 1.0.0-beta1 and it is still working. No idea why it didn't work initially.

Comment: It's the Cache of the Annotation processor... . :P If my answers helped, accept it to help others. Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

Same problem here, so I had to update my androidx.appcompat dependency, like below:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04'
```

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to implement this anymore.

Just extend your activity by AppCompatActivity which extends LifecycleOwner.

> This interface was deprecated in API level 1.0.0. Use
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity which extends LifecycleOwner,
>   so there are no use cases for this class.

You forgot to override

```
private final LifecycleRegistry lifecycleRegistry = new LifecycleRegistry(this);

@Override
public LifecycleRegistry getLifecycle() {
    return lifecycleRegistry;
}
```

You need at least Support-Lib [26.1](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#26-1-0)

Same for fragments. Just extend your Fragment by `LifecycleFragment` which extends `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Edit: Just rebuilt a quick sample project using Kotlin and it worked.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), HasSupportFragmentInjector, AnkoLogger {
    private val lifecycleRegistry by lazy { android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry(this) }
    private val viewModel by lazy { ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(BridgesVm::class.java) }
    override fun getLifecycle() = lifecycleRegistry

    public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel.data.observe(this, Observer<Bridge?> { info { "Received" } })
   }
}

class BridgesVm @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() { 
        val data: LiveData<Bridge> = MutableLiveData<Bridge>()
}
```

Edit:

There's a problem using arch version beta1. Consider using 1.0.0-alpha9-1 until this is fixed. In my case it wasnt working if i use beta1 but working with alpha 9-1

Comment: I have added activity and viewmodel class code. Kindly look into that.

Comment: Updated. Make sure to override getLifecycle().

Comment: I have already tried that. 
LifecycleRegistry mLifecycleRegistry = new LifecycleRegistry(this); 
The problem is same. It is saying that LifecycleRegistry(LifecycleOwner) can not be applied to packageName.BrowseActivity

Comment: Ive updated my code and rebuilt a very quick example and it was working.  Please try to invalidate your cache, and double-check your gradle file(s)

Answer (score 7):

use android jetpack, it'll solve your problem

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
```